# not able to acces db() from exported MongoClient module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, export

I am not able to export the client properly from `db.js` to `User.js`

**db.js**

```
const some= MongoClient.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING).then((client) =>{
    module.exports=client
    const app = require("./app")
    app.listen(process.env.PORT)
})
```

Using the client here , i can do methods like client.db().collection("users");

But i am not able to do using the user.js

**User.js**

```
const usersCollection = require("../db").db().collection("users");
```

This gives error saying const

```
usersCollection = require("../db").db().collection("users");
                                         ^
TypeError: require(...).db is not a function
```

Comment: Have you tried to export client from global scope? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong but in the callback function for MongoClient the first argument is the error and second argument is for client.(err,client)

so you are calling db() on error and not client

And also try to export from global scope as mentioned by Maxime in the comment

Answer (score -1):

You have this problem because you are importing something that is asynchronous and when you do it in 1 line the client is not ready when you try to call it with `db().collection("users")`.

You can verify if the async is the issue by changing your code to this:

```
const temp = require("../db")

setTimeout(() => {
  temp.db().collection("users")
}, 1000)
```

You can also check here for an example how to do the connection to the DB properly https://www.terlici.com/2015/04/03/mongodb-node-express.html

Comment: Its a promise and my code is in then() part so there doesn't arise "client not ready" condition

Comment: Actually, it is and it looks like you don't know how promises work with commonjs exports. If you have tried the code I've provided you would've seen that your issue is exactly because of the async part.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use connect the way you are using it. You should connect to the DB once and use the same connection throughout the life of your application.